# Reference counting a block of memory with GLib

Tags: c, glib, reference-counting

I'm starting with GLib and would like to use its GObject reference counting features to track when a piece of memory shared between threads can be deallocated. My use case would be as follows:

```
void sending_function() {
  char *msg = create_message(); // Allocates some memory at the heap.
  GObject *container = g_holds_my_pointer(msg, free);
  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
     g_object_ref(container);
     sends_to_other_thread(other_thread, container);
  }
}

void *other_thread(void *data) {
  GObject *container = data;
  char *msg = container->data;
  // Do something with msg...
  g_object_unref(container); // When the reference count reaches zero, frees msg.
}
```

Is there a simple container object that holds a single pointer and calls free on it after its reference count reaches 0? I've tried using GPtrArray with a single element, but the container is not a GObject to be reference-counted. Also, I wouldn't like to declare a complete GObject boilerplate just to this use case.

I recognize that this is a simple thing to implement yourself - create a struct holding a pointer and an atomic counter - but I'd prefer an already-tested implementation if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GByteArray for mutable data, GBytes for immutable data.  Neither are GObjects, but both are reference counted.

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Byte-Arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

GLib's reference counted box can be used to associate a (hidden) reference count to plan C data structures during allocation.

The memory can be allocated using `g_rc_box_alloc(size_t)` or `g_rc_box_new(type)`.

The reference count can be managed using:

```
g_rc_box_acquire(ptr)  // Increment refcount
g_rc_box_release(ptr)  // Decrement refcount, free the memory if refcount became 0
```

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Reference-counted-data.html